# I created a custom template for uib modal but when I start the server, the html file is not served

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a template for a uib modal like so

```
var instance = $uibModal.open({
       templateUrl: 'someDir/someTemplate.html',
       controller: 'someController'
  });
```

someTemplate.html does not get served when I check the "sources" tab in chrome's developers tool.

I test my server using Intellij and all the files seem to be served properly. But when I start my server with a jar I built with Intellij, it doesn't seem to serve the HTML template file even though I see it in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had the file typed out incorrectly. Its weird it works within Intellij though, even with the incorrect file name.